# Connecting 3 uart peripherals with esp32

Tags: max, esp32, uart, peripherals

I have 3 devices(GPS-Rx only, tft display-TxRx and a motor driver-Rx only) that connect only using uart. 2 of which only Tx, while one another has both Tx and Rx. I am using uart 0, for tx-rx peripheral. Flash mode and peripheral usage with device are separated with a push switch.
I also have a micro sd card requirement, so pins of uart1 has to be changed from spi pins.
I am using esp-idf and I am trying to use uart_set_pin. Now I have 2 questions,

1. How do I set no pin for Tx? Setting "UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE" would set it only to default Tx pin.
2. Can I use GPIO 16 and 17 for Rx pins of uart1 and uart2 respectively?

Comment: there is a SoftwareSerial library for Arduino on esp32

Comment: Is there a way to workout with idf? Our project is bound to idf as it gives lot of configurable options.

Comment: the esp32 Arduino is based on IDF so the internals of the library have to by compatible with IDF. https://github.com/plerup/espsoftwareserial

Comment: :). I tested it. I did the following 1. Set Tx of uart1 and uart2 to UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE; 2. assigning the pin gpio 17 to Rx of uart1.  3. assign the pin gpio 16.
Ran echo uart on uart 0 to test bidirectional test. Receive different texts over uart 1 and uart 2. It worked.